# Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean) in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I started a rails project today. I was working with devise to create a users model for my app. After the model was done being created I added the devise bootstrap gem. I added some some styling and then I ran,

`rails g devise:views:locale en`

Right after I ran this I got this waring,

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 41345
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
```

I read a little about this and I heard that is was a problem with thor. So I added gem 'thor', '0.19.1' to my gemfile. I then go the exact same error.

Any help would be appreciated.